# What will be the product if ethane reacts with SO2?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

At first I thought it was Reed's reaction but then I looked up the reaction and the reactant was actually $\ce{SO2Cl2}$ (sulfuryl chloride).

I couldn't find the product which would be produced when any alkane reacts with $\ce{SO2}$. Does it react and what would be the product?

Comment: AFAIK there is no reaction between SO2 and alkanes in the absence of other reagents

Comment: At what temperature? At room temp, likely nothing happens. At 1,000°C, likely there would be multiple products, as the molecules decompose and recombine.

Comment: Electronically excited SO2 do reacts with alkanes: https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/acs.jpca.8b04643

Comment: Methane is oxidized by SO2 at high T Other hydrocarbons might be also. https://ase.tufts.edu/nano-cel/publications/directReductionSO2.pdf#:~:text=Methane%20is%20an%20attractive%20reductant%2C%20due%20to%20abundant,the%20various%20elemental%20sulfur%20forms%20%28S2%2C%20S6%2C%20S8%29.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Alkanes can react with $\ce{SO_2}$ if the reaction is photoinitiated via via a hydrogen abstraction to form $\ce{HOSO^.}$ and organic radical $\ce{(R^.)}$ species and that reactivity is correlated with the energy required to break a C–H bond and the length of the alkane chain. you can find references [here](https://doi.org/10.1021/acs.jpca.8b04643)

Comment: For future reference: for the body of questions, answers, and comments, chemistry.se offers to use [mhchem](https://mhchem.github.io/MathJax-mhchem/) as a comfortable method to add chemical equations.